# Help with an asymptotic proof?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

I am having difficulty with a proof of an asymptotic result in maximum likelihood estimation theory. I don't believe any statistical theory however is needed to solve this problem, rather I think standard analysis will suffice. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Let $\{X_{1},...,X_{n}\}$ be a sequence of $iid$ random variables,  $X_{i}\in
\mathbb{R}$ for $i=1,...,n$, defined on a measure space $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{R},\lambda)$, where $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure. For $r,s,t=1,...,k$, let $\beta_{r}$, $\delta_{r}$, and $a_{rst}$ be functions of the random variables (and therefore of $n$). Suppose that for any $\epsilon,\eta>0$ there exists an $n_{0}(\epsilon,\eta)$, and an $T(\epsilon,\eta)<\infty$ such that for all $n>n_{0}$

(1):  $P[|\beta_{r}|<\eta\text{ and } |a_{rst}|<T]>1-\epsilon,\hspace{20pt}r=1,...,k$.

Then apparently using (1) the second term in the right-hand side of

(2):  $\delta_{r}=\beta_{r}+\sum_{s=1}^{k}\sum_{t=1}^{k}\delta_{s}\delta_{t}a_{rst},\hspace{20pt}r=1,...,k$,

can be made to be arbitrarily small as $\eta\rightarrow\infty$.

At first glance it seems that this result should be easy to obtain, but I cannot even do it for $k=1$. For example putting $k=1$ into (2) gives

$\delta_{1}=\beta_{1}+\delta_{1}^{2}a_{111}$,

which implies (for all $n>n_{0}$ and with probability greater than $1-\epsilon$)

$|\delta_{1}(1-\delta_{1}a_{111})|=|\beta_{r}|<\eta$.

I am having difficulty with the $(1-\delta_{1}a_{rst})$ term which is preventing me concluding that $\delta_{1}$ can be made to be arbitraily close to zero as $\eta\rightarrow\infty$. If I can show this then I think through induction I can show that the $\sum_{s=1}^{k}\sum_{t=1}^{k}\delta_{s}\delta_{t}a_{rst}$ term in (2) can also be made arbitrarily small as $\eta\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: $(\mathbb R, \mathscr R, \lambda)$ is not a probability space as $\lambda(\mathbb R) = \infty > 1$.

Comment: Well pointed out - thank-you. I should have said measure space.